# Split operating without concating

Tags: javascript, java

I have a string 'OR-xxxxxxxx-001-01'.
I need to split it as 'OR-xxxxxxx-001' and '01'. Is it possible without split by '-' and concatenating again ??

Comment: Where did the other zero go? `-01` or `-001`?

Comment: Java or Javascript? There's a big difference.

Comment: you could show your code how you did it via split, then request how to improve it!

Comment: I'm surprised by the number of answers considering 1) the OP has done no work of his own to solve this, and 2) we don't know what language the OP wants the code in.

Comment: OP: you might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Sry it will be 0001

Answer (score 1):

In Java, use [`lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-):

```
String string = "OR-xxxxxxxx-001-01";
int lastDash = string.lastIndexOf('-');

String prefix = string.substring(0, lastDash);  // OR-xxxxxxx-001
String suffix = string.substring(lastDash + 1); // 01
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for JavaScript (Java and JavaScript is not the same thing).

Since you don't want to split by - it's possible to do it with indexes. You haven't specified if it's of fixed length or not (which this solution depends on), but this should do the trick:

```
t = 'OR-xxxxxxxx-001-01'
str = t.slice(0, 12) + t.slice(16);
```

Will give `str = 'OR-xxxxxxxx-01'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a split with a positive look-ahead:

```
String str = "OR-xxxxxxxx-001-01";
String[] split = str.split("-(?=[^-]+$)");
```

- `[^-]`: any character other than `-`.
- `+`: repeated one or more times
- `$`: at the end of the String
- Then the `(?= ... )` is used for the positive look-ahead, so it won't be removed by the split. This means only the `-` outside the parenthesis act as delimiter to split on.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##TY7PCoMwDIfvPkUoO7SMFj0PGXsAGWxHcdDpGHX1D22UyfDZu0w9LJeE5Pt@pNajlnX1CqG02nvItGk/EUA/3K0pwaNGamNnKmjoxK/oTPvMC9DihwGsCwIdpMDOF/neSsZxIuOEHf4w8nxvDRJKglpmziQ/pvlNFvudYGLDJ4@PRnUDqp5EtC2v6VM1oLHq5JyevMJuDeVLjFjMOZpD@AI)

PS: In Java.